# Difference in weeks/months between two dates

Tags: vb.net, date

I need to find the difference between two dates with some constraints.

- if the difference in months is greater than 6, then display the difference in months
- if less than 6 months, display it in weeks
- finally, always round up to next whole number (6.2 weeks ---> 7)

i've tried this

```
    Dim startDate As Date = txtStartDate.DateValue
    Dim endDate As Date = txtEndDate.DateValue
    Dim dateDiff As TimeSpan = endDate - startDate

    Dim totalDays As Double = dateDiff.TotalDays
    'Divide by 7 to get the number of weeks
    Dim weeks As Double = totalDays / 7
    '6 months, average of 4.34812 weeks per month
    If (weeks >= 26.08872) Then
        txtDuration.Text = Math.Ceiling((weeks / 4.34812)).ToString() + " Months"
    Else
        txtDuration.Text = Math.Ceiling(weeks).ToString() + " Weeks"
    End If
```

it works for some dates, but not for every case.

- 2014/09/01 -> 2015/03/01 gives me 26 weeks, should be 6 months

Any ideas? is there a built in function in vb.net I could use to make it easier?

Thanks

Comment: there is 181 days between these dates, it is 25.857142857 weeks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marc,

try this.

```
diff = dateDiff(DateInterval.Month, startDate, endDate)

If (diff > 6) Then
    TxtDuration.Text = diff
Else
    TxtDuration.Text = dateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, startDate, endDate)
End If
```

You will have to rename the TimeSpan variable dateDiff, because it will conflict with the DateDiff Method.

I hope this helps

Comment: I modified the week part to be able to round up to next whole number.                                                          Dim days As Long = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, startDate1, endDate1)

txtFirstDuration.Text = Math.Ceiling(days / 7).ToString